# Laravel : How to count specific array values

Tags: php, laravel

I have been trubling with session array part...as my session array have 3 different value coming from database ...easy ...medium ...hard....how i count these specificly?

```
   Session::push('getscoresession',$getscore);
   Session::push('level',$level);


     $getsession = [  'qid' => $getidvalue,  'answer' => $getanswervalue];
     Session::push('answer', $getsession);


     $score = array_count_values(Session::get("level"));


     return view('score',compact('score'));
```

getting this error message: array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!`

Comment: So use count(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php `$count = count($array);`

Comment: want specific like my array has 3 easy 2 medium so it show specific array value

Comment: Please write your array here

Comment: Array ( [0] => easy [1] => easy [2] => easy [3] => medium [4] => medium [5] => medium [6] => hard [7] => hard [8] => hard [9] => hard [10] => )

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

```
$array = [
    0 => 'easy',
    1 => 'easy',
    2 => 'easy',
    3 => 'medium',
    4 => 'medium',
    5 => 'medium',
    6 => 'hard',
    7 => 'hard',
    8 => 'hard',
    9 => 'hard',
   10 => 'hard'
];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
var_dump(array_count_values($array));
```

Another solution:

```
// This is static
$stats = [
    'easy' => 0,
    'medium' => 0,
    'hard' => 0,
];

// Alternatively dynamic way:
$a = array_flip(array_unique($array));
$b = array_fill_keys(array_keys($a), 0);

foreach($array as $value) {
    $stats[$value]++; // Static Way
    $b[$value]++;  // Dynamic way
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($stats);
print_r($b);
exit;
```

You can use http://www.writephponline.com/ to execute above code.

In your blad file:

Use `foreach`

```
@foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {{ $key .'-'. $value }}
@endforeach
```

Let me know if you still have any query.

Comment: thanks i got your point but still error...                                                                                    ErrorException (E_WARNING)
array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!

Comment: Please check another solution

Comment: If it's useful to you and correct then you can correct my answer so others get help.

Comment: Ok, Good. have a great day

Comment: How can i show my array in blade part : Controller part --- $level = array_count_values(Session::get("level")); Array is -----Array ( [easy] => 3 [medium] => 2 ) how to print on blade so i get like this.... Easy - 3 medium - 2

Answer (score -1):

It's may be because you may have `null` values in your array.

Possible solutions :

1. Either remove `null` values from your array.
2. Or use `array_filter`.

See this example:
https://repl.it/repls/TameFarLine

Comment: Whichever answer was useful, please click right tick sign below answer so that appropriate user can get benefit of it and other community users also can get help.

Comment: How can i show my array in blade part :   Controller part ---  $level = array_count_values(Session::get("level"));                                                                                      Array is -----Array ( [easy] => 3 [medium] => 2 )                                                                 how to print on blade so i get like this....                                                                              Easy - 3                                                                                                                                  medium - 2

Comment: you have to use `@foreach` directive of blade. Go to Laravel.com for more documentation on blade.

Comment: Can any one please dare to comment why negative vote?